# Is it a good idea to store a large website menu in a PHP session?

Tags: php, performance, session

I've got an ecommerce site which has a quite big and complex menu system with many categories and subcategories. There are over a hundred entries.

Is it a good idea to store the whole thing in a string or in an array as PHP session variable, so that the navigation menu is not queried from the DB on each page again and again?

Or is to too large for a session variable?

Comment: The menus are all unique?

Comment: There is no way to known if is "too large" without actually seeing it. Caching it is more faster than query the database every time.

Comment: The whole thing is queried from the 'categories' table from mysql db.

Comment: @Farkas Does it vary from user-to-user? i.e. will user #1 have a totally different menu than user #2?

Comment: Sessions are per-user, on-disk by default, and this is a bad idea. Use an actual cache like Redis or Memcache to cache general application stuff. Also, you should use a profiler to see how long fetching the data from the database actually takes rather than just assuming "it's big and takes a long time".

Comment: @ceejayoz No, it is the same for everyone.

Comment: @Farkas In that case, it would be immensely wasteful to store it in sessions. You could cache it, but whatever you do should be shared storage. Session data is per-user so you'd be saving thousands of copies of the same big piece of data.

Comment: You both have a point there. I'll look for some caching solutions.

Comment: Querying the database for each http request will not be the slowest thing your page loads. Many, many very fast web pages do dozens of sql queries for a single rendering.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it a good idea to store the whole thing in a string or in an array as PHP session variable, so that the navigation menu is not queried from the DB on each page again and again?

No. Don't store data in the session which isn't specific to that session.

There are a lot of better options for caching this data; a couple of them are:

- Store it in the [APC user cache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apcu.php).
- Store it in [memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php).
- Write it out to a file using [`var_export`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php), then [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) that file to load it back in.
- Serialize it to a string using [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) or [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and save that to the database as a single row.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use any caching system for that.

For instance you can use APC (advanced PHP cache):

Install it (example for Debian-based unix):

```
sudo apt-get install php-apc
```

And actually use it:

```
function getMenuDataFromDatabaseWithCache()
{

// first - let's try to get results from cache
$cachedResults = apc_fetch('db_results');

// if there is a result - let's return it
if($cachedResults !== false) {
    return $cachedResults;
}

// if there is no results let's fetch all you need from the database
$fetchedResults = $mysql->someFunctionToGetData();

// store results in the cache for 1 day (1 day = 86400 seconds)
apc_add('db_results', $fetchedResults, 86400); 

// so hest time the function will return cached results, without fetching from DB
return $fetchedResults;

}
```